# Why git shows a merge conflict when the HEAD version has no content at the line

Tags: git, git-merge, merge-conflict-resolution, tree-conflict

I'm trying to do a `git merge master` from another branch, then I got this conflict:

```
<<<<<<< HEAD
=======
    t.text     "label_en"
    t.text     "help_text_en"
    t.text     "options_en"
>>>>>>> master
```

I know how to resolve the conflict, but I'm curious why does git recognize this as a conflict in the first place since the HEAD version has no content on the specific line.

```
<<<<<<< HEAD
=======
```

Isn't a simple case for git to just add the 3 lines from the master and merge it?

---

**Update:**

@Marcin is correct. Based on the answer, I did a test, let's say I have a git tree like below:

```
 A ---- B  (master)
      \
        C  (another branch)
```

content of `temp.txt` in `commit A`:

```
    t.text    "LALALA"
```

content of `temp.txt` in `commit B`:

```
    t.text    "label_en"
    t.text    "help_text_en"
    t.text    "options_en"
```

content of `temp.txt` in `commit C` is empty.

---

At this point, if I do:

```
git checkout another_branch
git merge master
```

Then I will get the following:

```
<<<<<<< HEAD
=======
    t.text     "label_en"
    t.text     "help_text_en"
    t.text     "options_en"
>>>>>>> master
```

Comment: To me similar happened when I clearly only added, nothing removed. git diff origin/main was also showing all added.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You made a change on that line on `master` and another branch, something was removed from that line on the latter and git isn't able to resolve that conflict automagically.